# Android Layout resize and multiple emulations

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, emulation

I am going to create an app for devices with Android OS 2.1 and higher. As many developer I met layout problems and after reading about that in the official android documentation I decided to follow a way; I created 6 directory one for every screen density (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi). What I want to know is if I did it right, I know that layout could be not exact at 100% but could I'll meet serious problems doing that?What I should do?

The second problem is checking app in many devices in the same time, I use Android Studio and I am able to create devices and use emulators but there is a plugin or a website or something else I can use to test quickly the app in tens of Android devices without set all manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: http://www.bluestacks.com/ and https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download

Comment: @Giridharan Thanks but with these I can emulate my app in a device, I would know if there is a tool that allow me to emulate app in a lot of device just uploading apk or doing some click

Comment: @Giridharan ok this isn't what I was looking for but this will help me a lot, thank you

Comment: That means you want to check your app with all the devices,right?